# how to extract a compressed zip file in IPYTHON?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I am starting to learn IPYTHON from a book by running code hands on. As given in the book I am not able to run the code with the same output or without error, I am kind of stuck here at this line with an error.

I can find out how to extract a zip file online in a different context from other sources but I would want to troubleshoot this problem so that I know how to handle an error or troubleshoot things later as I proceed. I would want to know what is wrong here that is giving out an error while the same did not show an error to the author of the book. Am I missing any detail here? did I miss changing a file name according to the context etc. Here is the code and error in the environment I was running.

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import urllib2, zipfile

In [2]: url = 'http://ipython.rossant.net/'

In [3]: filename = 'facebook.zip'

In [4]: downloaded = urllib2.urlopen(url + filename)

In [5]: folder = 'data'

In [6]: mkdir $folder
A subdirectory or file data already exists.

In [7]: mkdir $folder1

In [8]: cd $folder1
C:\Users\think\Documents\Python Scripts\$folder1

In [9]: with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   ...:     f.write(downloaded.read())
   ...:

In [10]: with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as zip:
   ....:     zip.extractall('.')
   ....:
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipfile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e24f3f3a7f9c> in <module>()
----> 1 with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as zip:
      2     zip.extractall('.')
      3

C:\Users\think\Anaconda\lib\zipfile.pyc in __init__(self, file, mode, compressio
n, allowZip64)
    768         try:
    769             if key == 'r':
--> 770                 self._RealGetContents()
    771             elif key == 'w':
    772                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets writte
n

C:\Users\think\Anaconda\lib\zipfile.pyc in _RealGetContents(self)
    809             raise BadZipfile("File is not a zip file")
    810         if not endrec:
--> 811             raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
    812         if self.debug > 1:
    813             print endrec

BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

In [11]:
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated .

Comment: Have you even **pretended** to read the error message?

Comment: nope, I did not pretend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem: see [this link](http://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/27c6cm/trouble_downloading_a_zip_with_ipython/). The problem basically comes from a misconfiguration in the server that contains the file: downloading this file from Python sometimes results in a corrupted file. Easiest fix is just to download manually the file through your web browser and extract it in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You simply named the file `facebook.zip`, that doesn't make it into a zip file (which is why you are getting that error). Just like if I create a text file `hello.txt` and then rename it to `hello.png` it would not be converted to an image.

Try reading it as a normal file:

```
with open(filename) as foo:
   for line in foo:
      print(line)
```

Comment: Yes, it totally does not make sense to give a .zip extension to a file I downloaded if its not a zip file, but I thought it was the correct way because the book said so. I was thinking I was wrong. I just followed every line of code whatever was given in the book.

Comment: The url downloaded is a zip file.

Comment: Is it conceivable that the book could be wrong? Do NOT blindly accept what a book says, but instead evaluate it to see if it makes sense. If it doesn't then triangulate the information to determine whether the book is right or wrong. There are horrible books out there that should never have been published.